# How to make change in Android live application without using any third party software as Hansel is doing?

Tags: android, performance

I want to build a platform through which I can make the changes in my live android application.
Currently, Hansel.io is doing the same but I want to create my own such platform.

Any help would be really helpful and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Its a kind of hotfix that I want to put in android application.

Answer (score 0):

You should be use  [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/products/remote-config/)

Make changes to your app's default behavior and appearance by changing server-side parameter values. For example, you could change your app's color theme to match a seasonal promotion or change the start date of a sale with no need to publish an app update.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But you are talking about adding runtime behavior. And I want to handle the Crashes of application at runtime.